# Unknown props pattern

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

In the code below there is way of writing react components that I've never seen before and I could not find any explanation. It is the below snippet that I struggle with.

```
const Reservations = ({
  clearReservations,
  handleSubmit,
  machine,
  saveReservations,
}) => (
```

Am I passing a props here? 
What is handleSubmit? There isn't any definition of it. Does it have anything to do with redux-form?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, FieldArray, Form } from 'redux-form';
import { Button, Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import _map from 'lodash/map';
import ReactJson from 'react-json-view';

import { WEEK_DAYS } from '../common/constants';
import {
  clearReservations,
  saveReservations,
} from '../actions/machine';
import SingleDayReservations from './SingleDayReservations';
import './Reservations.scss';

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {
    // monday: [{ start: 'must be present' }],
    //tuesday: { _error: 'error' },
  };
  return errors;
};

const Reservations = ({
  clearReservations,
  handleSubmit,
  machine,
  saveReservations,
}) => (
  <Container className="reservations">
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(saveReservations)}>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={8}>
          <h2>Reservations</h2>
          {_map(WEEK_DAYS, day => (
            <FieldArray
              key={`single-${day}`}
              component={SingleDayReservations}
              name={day}
            />
          ))}
          <Button color="primary" type="submit">
            Save data
          </Button>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={4}>
          <ReactJson src={machine} name="machineStoreState" />
          <Button
            onClick={clearReservations}
            color="warning"
            className="reservations__clear-btn"
          >
            Reset Data
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Form>
  </Container>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  machine: state.machine,
  initialValues: state.machine,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  clearReservations,
  saveReservations,
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'reservations',
    validate,
    enableReinitialize: true,
  })(Reservations),
);
```

---

handleSubmit comes from redux-form

Comment: It's just destructuring the parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a functional component the first argument passed is `props`, the line you referenced could also be written in the following way.

```
const Reservations = (props) => {
  const { clearReservations, handleSubmit, machine, saveReservations } = props; // <- Object Destructuring
}
```

What they are doing here is something called `Object Destructuring` that was introduced in ES6.
You can read more about it here [ES6 In Depth: Destructuring](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `props` to the component, you use destructuring and take out only those things that you really need.

It would be the same as writing

```
const Reservations = (props) => .... 

{ clearReservations,
  handleSubmit,
  machine,
  saveReservations } = props
```

[You can find more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is just `destructuring`, here a example:

```js
let someObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};

const destruct = ({ a, b, c }) => {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

destruct(someObject);
```

So, you "destruct" some object and get the properties you want from that object.